# Как расположить текст справа от checkbox?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, checkbox, radio

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
body{
    background-color: black; 
    color: gray;
}
#box {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#box ~ label::before {
  content: '\25A2';  
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
#box:checked ~ label::before {
  content: '\2713';  
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color:#5F9EA0;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 2px inset #000;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
}
  </style>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="cat_wr">
  <form>
   <input id="box" type="checkbox" class='terms-checkbox' />
        <label for="box"><span class='text'>Этим сообщением я хочу показать, <br> что галочка остается около первой строки текста.</span></label>
</form>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Никак не могу найти информацию, вторую строчку пишет под чекбоксом

Comment: Попробуйте добавить: `#box ~ label { display: flex; }`

Answer (score 0):

Добавил обёртку с классом `field-wrapper` и стилизовал его `label`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: gray;
}

.field-wrapper>label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#box~label::before {
  content: '\25A2';
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

#box:checked~label::before {
  content: '\2713';
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 2px inset #000;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="field-wrapper">
    <input id="box" type="checkbox" class='terms-checkbox' />
    <label for="box">
      <span class='text'>
        Этим сообщением я хочу показать, 
        <br> 
        что галочка остается около первой строки текста.
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
```